# Should a user be a schema owner in order to read, write, and execute SPs?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, privileges, database-security

My webapp needs to read, write (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), and execute stored procedures on a SQL 2008 database with five schemas.

I created a user that authenticates through SQL, and granted the user db_datareader, db_datawriter, and db_procedureexec through Security -> Logins -> (Username) Properties -> User Mappings.  I then configured the app to connect to the database using the username and the proper password, but upon attempting to execute a stored procedure, got this error:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object '(stored procedure name)', database '(new database)', schema '(schema 1)'.
```

Finding this user in the Security section of the database, I made it the owner of the five schemas in the DB.

Did I grant too many privileges?  Should an application-level user be a schema owner in order to read, write, and exec procedures?

Comment: Did you define the permissions on the right database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an app user should not need to be a schema owner in order to read, write and exec procedures.

You can say things like:

```
GRANT EXEC ON SCHEMA::whatever TO [user];
```

This will allow them to execute procedures in the [whatever] schema. In order to not require transitive privileges (e.g. say your procedures execute dynamic SQL), you can consider setting them to `EXECUTE AS OWNER`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to grant an application user ownership of a database.  This essentially gives them cart blanche.  What you should do is to grant `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles to the user, and grant execute on all applicable stored procedures and functions.